# jquery mouseleave ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was wondering if it is possible for an ajax request to be triggered from a mouseleave function? I would like the string 'Y' to be sent on when the mouse leaves the `li` so it can be updated in the database.

is this possible by any chance?

```
(function(){
  $('li#myId').mouseenter(function(){
    var y = 'Y';
  }).mouseleave(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'update.php',
      data: 'y='+y,
      success: function(response){
        $('li.#myId').html(response);
      }

    });
  });
```

})();

Comment: Why not? You just need move `var y` outside first closure, because it is local

Comment: And, of course, you have errors in your code. `$('li.#myId') -> $('li#myId')` and even `$('li#myId') -> $('#myId')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just store `y` as data.

```
(function(){
    var postY = function (y) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'update.php',
          data: 'y='+y,
          success: function(response){
              $('#myId').html(response);
          }
        });
    };

    // li#myId using both a tag and id is unnecessary since id is unique
    $('#myId').mouseenter(function(e){
        $(this).data('y', 'Y');
    }).mouseleave(function(e){
        postY($(this).data('y'));
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you declare the "y" variable inside a function it will only be available for that function. you should declare it after your $(document).ready function and change it on the event. than you can send it via ajax when the mouseleave event is fired.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var y = 'Y'
  $('li#myId').mouseenter(function(){
     // whatever you want to do here with "y"
  });

  $('li#myId').mouseleave(function(){
     // ajax
  });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't miss use global variables that way. Also separate your code, don't bloat your `$(document).ready` functions.